# Toxicity of Zinc to fungi

Tags: microbiology, toxicology, mycology

I would like to know what are the mechanisms and overall effects of Zinc on fungi. 
I know that *Candida albicans* is susceptible to Zinc deprivation and Zinc-infused paint is also used to repel mold.

Comment: http://goo.gl/sPhcyn and http://goo.gl/wrIX58 might be of interest to you

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC243165/pdf/aem00215-0132.pdf) (PDF) too. I couldn't find definitive reports on mechanisms of Zn toxicity on fungi, so it doesn't seem that the exact cause is known yet.